# What is the best approach to hooking up database in FastAPI?

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I found two approaches to working with databases in FastAPI. Are there any fundamental differences? if so which approach is preferable?

**Approach 1**
This is found in official FastAPI-fullstack  [example](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/api/deps.py) :

```py
from fastapi import Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


def get_current_user(
    db: Session = Depends(get_db), token: str = Depends(reusable_oauth2)
) -> models.User:
    ...
```

**Approach 2**
Following approach found in official [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-sql-databases/), some blogs and also in `fastapi_users` package documentation:

```py
import databases

DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test.db"
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    await database.connect()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await database.disconnect()
```

**Edit (2021-09-06) - Approach 3**

Another way recommended in the new SQLModel package docs by tiangolo himself. This seems like just a variant of the first approach above, but for sake of completeness:

https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/session-with-dependency/

```
sqlite_file_name = "database.db"
sqlite_url = f"sqlite:///{sqlite_file_name}"

connect_args = {"check_same_thread": False}
engine = create_engine(sqlite_url, echo=True, connect_args=connect_args)

def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session

# Code here omitted 

@app.post("/heroes/", response_model=HeroRead)
def create_hero(*, session: Session = Depends(get_session), hero: HeroCreate):
    db_hero = Hero.from_orm(hero)
    session.add(db_hero)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(db_hero)
    return db_hero
```

Comment: Depends on the database. For Postgres (the first approach) you may want to not keep a connection open all the time (e.g. hogging connection slots on the server). For Sqlite, that doesn't matter (since it's a local file).

Comment: It looks like the second method uses [encode/databases](https://github.com/encode/databases) as a quick way to get asyncio support, which until recently wasn't available for sqlAlchemy. The first way uses dependency injection, which is really handy for testing. It's not clear if tests will be as convenient using the second method.

Comment: The first one is also from the FastAPI documentation, so both cases will just work. The first one is based on SQLAlchemy's Session support. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency

Comment: @AKX but isn't it worse to establish the connection at every route call? Could you elaborate further? Thanks

Comment: Depends. Many database drivers can pool connections, so you don't need to pay the connection latency on every request, but you also don't necessarily keep a single connection alive at all times.

Comment: Neither connects to the database for each call; the SQLAlchemy one creates a session - which is not the same as a connection, and the encode one connects on startup.